# Get the latest file and compare its filename with the rest of the files

Tags: powershell, filenames, get-childitem

I want to get the latest file in a directory and use its filename without the *(Count)* to check if it has same names with the rest of the files.

If filename matches, Rename it as $(Get-Date -Format yyyymmddhhmmss)_$ScreenTitle and move it to Output folder.

If not, Do nothing.

**EDIT:**

These are the default filenames from the Xbox Gamebar Screenshot (Win+Alt+PrtSc):

[image]

The code below works properly, (Thanks @Theo!)
but I've figured-out that filename's time changes, so it does not match the regex.

```
$ParentFolder = "$env:USERPROFILE\Videos\Captures"
#Set-Location $ParentFolder

# Create an Output Folder wether It's Existing or Not
New-Item $ParentFolder\Output -Force -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
$OutputFolder = ".\Output"

Get-ChildItem -Path $ParentFolder -Filter '*.png' -File | Group-Object {$_.BaseName.Split("(")[0].TrimEnd()} | 
Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } | ForEach-Object {
    # get the latest file
    $newestFile = $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
    $newestFile

    If ($newestFile.BaseName -match '^(.+)\s+(\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{4}\s+\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}\s+[ap]m).*$') {
        $screentitle      = $matches[1]
        $dateFromFileName = $matches[2]  # the date from the filename unaltered like '11_21_2022 10_59_21 AM'
        
        $dateToday = Get-Date -Format "yyyymmddhhmmss"

        # create the new filename
        $NewFileName = '{0}_[{1}]{2}' -f $dateToday, $screenTitle, $newestFile.Extension

        # Move the file with a new name to the destination
        Write-Host "Moving file '$($newestFile.Name)' as '$NewFileName'"
        $newestFile | Move-Item -Destination (Join-Path -Path $OutputFolder -ChildPath $NewFileName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit unclear if you want to use the date that is part of the file name in the moved file or the curent date.
You also do not say in what format that date should be when using it in the new file name.

See the comments in the code below for alternatives on the date

```
$ParentFolder = 'Z:\WhereTheFilesAre'
$OutputFolder = 'X:\TheSestinationFolder'

Get-ChildItem -Path $ParentFolder -Filter '*.png' -File | Group-Object {$_.BaseName.Split("(")[0].TrimEnd()} | 
Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } | ForEach-Object {
    # get the latest file
    $newestFile = $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
    if ($newestFile.BaseName -match '^(.+)\s+(\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{4}\s+\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}\s+[ap]m).*$') {
        $screentitle      = $matches[1]
        $dateFromFileName = $matches[2]  # the date from the filename unaltered like '11_21_2022 10_59_21 AM'

        # if you want the date from the file name formatted like 'yyyy_MM_dd HH-mm-ss'
        # $date = [datetime]::ParseExact($dateFromFileName, 'MM_dd_yyyy h_mm_ss tt', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
        # $dateFromFileName = '{0:yyyy_MM_dd HH-mm-ss}' -f $date

        # create the new filename
        $NewFileName = '{0}_[{1}]{2}' -f $dateFromFileName, $screenTitle, $newestFile.Extension

        # Move the file with a new name to the destination
        Write-Host "Moving file '$($newestFile.Name)' as '$NewFileName'"
        $newestFile | Move-Item -Destination (Join-Path -Path $OutputFolder -ChildPath $NewFileName)

        # what do you want to do with the rest of the files that were older? Delete them?
        # $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Remove-Item
    }
}
```

---

As per your comment, below an updated answer:

```
$ParentFolder = 'Z:\WhereTheFilesAre'
$OutputFolder = 'X:\TheSestinationFolder'

Get-ChildItem -Path $ParentFolder -Filter '*.png' -File | 
Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '^(.+)\s+(\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{4}\s+\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}\s+[ap]m).*$' } |  # filter more specific
Group-Object { $_.BaseName -replace '\s+\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{4}\s+\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}\s+[ap]m.*$' } |       # group on screen title
Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } | ForEach-Object {
    # get the latest file
    $newestFile   = $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
    $screentitle  = $_.Name

    # scenario 1: Take the date from the file name
    $dateFromFileName = $newestFile.BaseName -replace '^.+\s+(\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{4}\s+\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}\s+[ap]m).*$', '$1'
    # parse the date from the file name
    $date = [datetime]::ParseExact($dateFromFileName, 'MM_dd_yyyy h_mm_ss tt', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
    # create the new filename
    $NewFileName = '{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}_[{1}]{2}' -f $date, $screenTitle, $newestFile.Extension

    # scenario 2: Use the LastWriteTime property from the newest file (much easier)
    # $NewFileName = '{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}_[{1}]{2}' -f $newestFile.LastWriteTime, $screenTitle, $newestFile.Extension

    # Move the file with a new name to the destination
    Write-Host "Moving file '$($newestFile.Name)' as '$NewFileName'"
    $newestFile | Move-Item -Destination (Join-Path -Path $OutputFolder -ChildPath $NewFileName)

    # what do you want to do with the rest of the files that were older? Delete them?
    # $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Remove-Item
}
```

Comment: Hi! @Theo, Thanks again for these :) I ran your code once it works just what I like but after restarting the ISE, the code doesn't proceed to -match regex anymore. What could go wrong?

Comment: @jeriru Difficult to say.. Are here any files left in the Parentfolder and if so, do they have the same format as the examples you gave? Can you give new examples of the filenames that do not match anymore?

Comment: Yes @Theo and I already saw that the regex doesn't match anything because the time format from the filename changes. How should I change it? should I add another If condition? Kindly check the edited post for the filenames thank you!